# How to create a dsicrete probability distribution function from a discretised probability mass function

Tags: r

So I used the 'actuar' package in R to discretise a continuous gamma cdf, returning a probability mass function.

Attempting to turn the probability mass function I generated into a cumulative distribution function:

```
disc.gamma.cdf <- function(y)
{
values <- discretize(pgamma(x, 20, 0.2), 
from = 0, to = 300, method = "rounding")
result <- sum(values[0:y])
return(result)
}
```

But when I wish to sum the discrete.gamma.cdf over a certain range of values, I am returned with an error:

```
    i <- 0:4
    sum(disc.gamma.cdf(i))
    Warning message:
In 0:y : numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used
```

Not that great with R, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it almost right. The main thing to remember is that R array indexes start from 1, and that a function will not automatically work on arrays, it has to be vectorised.

So, with two changes your code is right:

```
disc.gamma.cdf <- function(y)
{
   values <- discretize(pgamma(x, 20, 0.2), 
                        from = 0, to = 300, method = "rounding")
   result <- sum(values[1:y])  # From 1 not 0
   return(result)
}
i <- 1:5
sum(  sapply(i, disc.gamma.cdf) )
```

`sapply(i, disc.gamma.cdf)` calls the function along each of the elemnts of i, and then you sum it.

If you want a vectorised version of your code, you can do this:

```
disc.gamma.cdf <- function(y)
{
   values <- discretize(pgamma(x, 20, 0.2), 
                        from = 0, to = 300, method = "rounding")
   cumsum(values)[y]  # last expression is returned anyway
}
i <- 1:5
sum(  disc.gamma.cdf(i) )
```

The function `cumsum` calculates all possible sums, and now you can just subset that by a vector.